# how to extract IP address and port number from of wireless packet

Tags: python, udp, wireless, tcp, scapy

I want information like IP address, flag, protocol from IP layer and Port number and other information from TCP/UDP layer for an wireless packet. I am capturing packet using SCAPY and PYTHON... After getting this I will store this detail in mysql so detail need to be in that format so that it can be stored in database column

Comment: Just as a reference point - you might wanna check out https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang - its not python - but it can give a good point of ref/ideas.

Comment: You might want to check http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html#quick-demo